# LitElement equivalent of React "key" concept

Tags: lit-element, lit-html

```
<example name="One"></example>
<example name="Two"></example>
<example name="Three"></example>
```

Next render looks like this:

```
<example name="Four"></example>
<example name="Three"></example>
```

LitElement will remove the last element and update the first two with new properties.

How do I change this so that LitElement removes all elements except `name="three"` and a new element is created with `name="Four"` on first position?

Using React, this would be accomplished by giving them a key property. I want to achieve the same result using LitElement.

```
<example key="1" name="One"></example>
<example key="2" name="Two"></example>
<example key="3" name="Three"></example>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this you want to use the lit-html `repeat` directive. From [the docs](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/writing-templates#repeating-templates-with-the-repeat-directive):

> The repeat directive performs efficient updates of lists based on
>   user-supplied keys:
>
> `repeat(items, keyFunction, itemTemplate)`
>
> Where:
>
> - `items` is an Array or iterable.
> - `keyFunction` is a function that takes a single item as an argument and returns a guaranteed unique key for that item.
> - `itemTemplate` is a template function that takes the item and its current index as arguments, and returns a `TemplateResult`.
>
> For example:
>
> ```js
> const employeeList = (employees) => html`
>   <ul>
>     ${repeat(employees, (employee) => employee.id, (employee, index) => html`
>       <li>${index}: ${employee.familyName}, ${employee.givenName}</li>
>     `)}
>   </ul>
> `;
> ```
>
> If you re-sort the `employees` array, the `repeat` directive reorders
>   the existing DOM nodes.

To use `repeat` you'll need to import it from lit-html:

```js
import {repeat} from 'lit-html/directives/repeat';
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is related to the question

Comment: The `key` function identifies which index belongs to what render. This way it can behave as requested